# How to have .replaceText () erase blank parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script that takes a row a from a spreadsheet and replaces placeholders in a document if the column name matches. I use the `%placeHolder%` format. The `replaceText()` method works perfectly, but if that field is blank, how can I have it replace the place holder to blank or "N/A"? I've tried a couple different routes but am probably missing something simple.

```
function formatTemplate(){
  var postFlightTemplate = DocsList.getFileById('templateKey').makeCopy().getId();

  var template = DocumentApp.openById(postFlightTemplate);
  var templateHeader = template.getHeader();
  var templateBody = template.getActiveSection();

  var flightLog = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetKey');
  var sheet = flightLog.getSheetByName('Flight Tracking');
  var data = ScriptsLib.getRowsData(sheet, sheet.getRange('A2:2'), 1);

  var keys = ScriptsLib.getKeys(data[0]);

  for (var key in keys){
    Logger.log('key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
    if (data[0][keys[key]] != null || data[0][keys[key]] != ''){
      templateHeader.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
    }else{
      Logger.log('empty key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', 'N/A');
    }
  }
  template.setName('RR-'+data[0].incidentNumber+'-'+data[0].flightNumber);
  template.saveAndClose();

  MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'Post Flight Report','See Run Report', {name: 'P1AR Flight Log', attachments: template});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say, but apparently you're using a library, "ScriptsLib". I've done searches, but can't find any public code with both `getRowsData` and `getKeys` methods, so it's probably a private library.

I need to do some guessing about what those two functions do. If you can provide the source for them from your ScriptsLib, it would help to validate or revise my guesses, which are:

- ScriptsLib is based on the sample code from [Working with Spreadsheet Data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets#writing-code), which has getRowsData and some supporting functions in it.
- Method `getKeys` is similar to the [function of the same name in Class UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties#getKeys%28%29).

The `getRowsData` method creates an array of objects, by calling `getObjects`. The `getObjects` method iterates over the given range creating an array of objects with named properties from each row. *If there is a blank cell in a row, there will be no property with the name for that column.*

In your code, you loop over the keys contained in `data[0]`, which will be incomplete (missing properties) when there were blanks in the source data, because of the way `getObjects` works. That means that you never really process the blanks, and don't have an opportunity to replace the relevant keys with "N/A".

What you need to do then, is loop over the key values that are in the template document - and those are probably represented by the headings in the spreadsheet. (...after normalization to camelCase, that is).

```
var keys = ScriptsLib.normalizeHeaders(sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues()[0]);
```

That will give us the full list of keys to iterate over. But we're not done yet.

You've got a bug in the logic that checks whether you have a property. Look at this line:

```
if (data[0][keys[key]] != null || data[0][keys[key]] != ''){
```

With an OR operator there, you will end up executing the IF block when 
`data[0][keys[key]]` *is null*. You've written an else clause that should replace a key with "N/A", but it's not going to get executed.

```
                            :: when data[0][keys[key]] == null
data[0][keys[key]] != null  :: false
data[0][keys[key]] != ''    :: true (because null != '')
```

You probably meant to use AND.

```
if (data[0][keys[key]] != null && data[0][keys[key]] != ''){
```

That *should* make things work the way you want. But I'd suggest explicitly dealing with the possibility that a data object won't have a property with a particular key name, and getting around that and/or bug at the same time. JavaScript gives us `hasOwnProperty()` to do that.

```
if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(keys[key])) // property is present
```

The refactored code becomes:

```
function formatTemplate(){
  var postFlightTemplate = DocsList.getFileById('templateKey').makeCopy().getId();

  var template = DocumentApp.openById(postFlightTemplate);
  var templateHeader = template.getHeader();
  var templateBody = template.getActiveSection();

  var flightLog = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetKey');
  var sheet = flightLog.getSheetByName('Flight Tracking');
  var data = ScriptsLib.getRowsData(sheet, sheet.getRange('A2:2'), 1);

  var keys = ScriptsLib.normalizeHeaders(sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues()[0]); 

  for (var key in keys){
    if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(keys[key])) { // property is present
      Logger.log('key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateHeader.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
    }else{
      Logger.log('empty key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', 'N/A');
    }
  }
  template.setName('RR-'+data[0].incidentNumber+'-'+data[0].flightNumber);
  template.saveAndClose();

  MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'Post Flight Report','See Run Report', {name: 'P1AR Flight Log', attachments: template});
}
```

Comment: Nice digging again :-)  I'm impressed by the logic of your answer ...+1

Comment: Mogs to the rescue again.  Thanks man and you must have ESP because you read right into that library. Sorry for forgetting that.

Answer (score 2):

You could check out the following section of your code, with two comments I have added at the end of a couple of lines:

```
for (var key in keys){
    Logger.log('key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
    if (data[0][keys[key]] != null || data[0][keys[key]] != undefined){ // I changed this to undefined
      templateHeader.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', data[0][keys[key]]);
    }else{
      Logger.log('empty key:'+keys[key]+' / value:'+data[0][keys[key]]);
      templateHeader.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', 'N/A'); // I added this row
      templateBody.replaceText('%'+keys[key]+'%', 'N/A');
    }
  }
```